# VB.NET While loop call application.DoEvents once a second

Tags: .net, loops, user-interface, while-loop

I am making an application that involves copying files and showing the stats in a progressbar and label. Currently i am using variables to hold the current progress, application.doevents inside the loop to avoid making the application irresponsive, and a timer that retreives the stats from the variables and updates the label and progressbar in GUI. Is there a better way of doing this? I am worried that the application.doevents inside the while loop is a bit costly... Is there a way to only call the application.doevents once a second? thanks.

Comment: Just add a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Learn to use the BackgroundWorker to avoid using the DoEvents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a really good reason to do so (and I'm not aware of any), don't use `DoEvents`.  It may not cause any issues in your particular scenario but in general it's best to not be in the habit of using it.  A quick Google search will find you lots of discussion on this subject.

Far better would be to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to handle copying the files and updating the variables and use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to update the GUI every second.

You'd put it together something like this...

```
BackgroundWorker Worker;
Timer UpdateTimer;

void Run()
{
    Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    Worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
    Worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    UpdateTimer = new Timer();
    UpdateTimer.Tick += UpdateTimer_Tick;
    UpdateTimer.Interval = 1000;
    UpdateTimer.Start();
}

void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //do file copying
}

void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //update gui
}
```

Edit: Realized after posting my code is C# but you're working in VB.  I'm not really familiar with the VB syntax but this still applies.  Just check out the MSDN links for those two classes and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use little math to achieve that if you don't want to use background worker.

```
for j=1 to 1000

     'your code

    if (j mod 25)=0 then  ' 
       Application.Doevents()
    endif

next
```

with this approach instead of hitting doevents 1000 times hits only 40 times.